# Increment integer value of a textview depends on other textview content

Tags: java, android

I'm newbie, and  I want to change the value of a textview1only if the value of textview 2 become superior to 50. 
P.s: (I want to increment its value)

Any suggestions !

Comment: Please post the code you have been working with. Then we can help you from there. But for starters you will want to look at the `TextWatcher` class.

Comment: Thank you @Barns I just have the idea, I still not figured out how to transform it to a code. 

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Say we have two textviews - textviewA and textviewB. You want textviewA to change when textviewB's value changes. You do something like this (I am assuming you have declared and done findViewById for these textviews).

```
textviewB.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()){
//You override three methods here beforeTextChanged(),onTextChanged() and //afterTextChanged(). Since you are dealing with changing a textview's value //after the other textview has changed, you could use afterTextChanged()
...

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
if (editable != null){
String textInEditable = editable.toString();
int number = Integer.parseInt(textInEditable);
if (number > 50){
textviewA.setText("Whatever text you want");
//as Keara mentioned in the comment below, the number would simply be incremented with 1 so number++ before you set the number to the textview.
}}}
```

Something along those lines

Comment: They want to increment the value, so "whatever you want" should be Integer.parseInt(textViewA.getText()) +1

Comment: @Keara, thanks for that. I would update the code now.

Comment: Thank you Samuel, But for textviewB it shows a number that changes continuously, and when it becomes superior to 50 even if its value still superior to 50, textviewA should increment just one step. And do not increment again until textviewB becomes inferior to 50 and jump above 50.

Comment: @JoeBa I do not understand. Can you clarify what you mean by changes continuously?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to increment text1's value only when text2's value crosses 50 which means if text2 crosses 50 and stays above 50, text1's value should increment only once.

**Modifying Samuel Agbede's answer**

```
 boolean isValueChanged = true;
    textViewB.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()){    
       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
          if (editable != null){
             String textInEditable = editable.toString();
             int number = Integer.parseInt(textInEditable);
             if (number > 50 && isValueChanged){
                textViewA.setText(String.valueOf(number+1));
                isValueChanged = false;
             }
             if (number < 50){
                isValueChanged = true;
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

This way you'll have the increment working only when the number goes above 50 again and again.
So, if the number goes to 51 it will increment and if it goes from 51 to suppose 60, it won't increment unless value goes below 50 first which is what you want.

`isValueChanged` above is to assure that it won't increment the value of `textViewA` repetitively and only increment when values go in a sequence `above 50->below50->above 50`.

And the value being incremented here is the value of `textViewB` which means if `textViewB` contains 101 then `textViewA` will contain 102, you can modify it as your need